# Why is $t$ used instead of $t_r$ in this step in deriving the retarded potential?

Tags: electromagnetism

On page 446 of Griffiths, he tries to prove the retarded potential $V$ satisfies the inhomogeneous wave equation.

The last equation in the proof is:

[image]
Why is the last term in this equation $\rho(\mathbf{r}, t)$ instead of $\rho(\mathbf{r}, t_r)$, where $t_r$ is the retarded time? Isn't the $\rho$ in the integrand $\rho(\mathbf{r}', t_r)$?

Comment: Could you please tell us what is meant with $\cal R$  (the argument of the 3-dim $\delta$-function respectively the denominator below $\ddot{\rho}$ ?

Comment: @Frederic_Thomas: Griffiths uses the script (r) to denote the vector between r and r'. So consider it to be $(r - r')$

Answer (score 2):

Now I know the answer: $t_r=t$ when $\mathbf{r'}=\mathbf{r}$.